# PHP/MYSQL: less than or equal to 50 is displaying records in the hundreds?

Tags: php, mysql, operators

Heres the query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status='live' and price<='50' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

It is showing all items under $50. But then it also shows all items over $100? I'm guessing this issue has something to do with these prices being triple digits. Other thing to mention is that the prices also include .00 after their price.

Any pointers?

Comment: How has your data been stored is that a string?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have 50 in quotes.  MySql is probably treating it like a string.

```
... AND price <= 50 ORDER BY ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If the price column datatype is "CHAR" (string), "100", and "49999" are both <= "50".  Change one or both data types (columns and comparison) to DECIMAL(10,2) or another numeric type.